# Trouble in Installing through pip3

Tags: proxy, pip

I am trying to install packages through pip3

```
pip3 install keras
```

But, the error is as follows:

```
Collecting keras
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 792, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 521, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 405, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 303, in get_connection
    proxy_manager = self.proxy_manager_for(proxy)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 197, in proxy_manager_for
    **proxy_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 440, in proxy_from_url
    return ProxyManager(proxy_url=url, **kw)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 391, in __init__
    raise ProxySchemeUnknown(proxy.scheme)
urllib3.exceptions.ProxySchemeUnknown: Not supported proxy scheme
```

My institute needs a proxy and I updated proxy at all places in my system using [ProxyMan](https://github.com/himanshub16/ProxyMan).

Is it due to proxy? Because I had fresh install of Linux. If because of proxy, where do i need to update proxy?

Comment: How do you pass proxy options to `pip`?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I solved it by adding my proxy settings at the end of /etc/bash.bashrc like this:

```
export http_proxy="http://<user>:<pass>@<proxy>:<port>
export https_proxy="https://<user>:<pass>@<proxy>:<port>
export ftp_proxy="ftp://<user>:<pass>@<proxy>:<port>
export socks_proxy="socks://<user>:<pass>@<proxy>:<port>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `easy_install + packagename` instead of `pip`.

Comment: It looks more like comment then an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead); instead, provide [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) that don't require clarification from the asker.